# Using DTO as fields in another DTO

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbctemplate, dto

I have two entity and two corresponding tables in DB

```
public class Book {
    private int id;
    private int authorId;
    private String title;
    private int year;

    // getter setter;
}

public class Author {
   private int id;
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName; 

   // getter setter;
}
```

I need to send in RestController list of next DTO (List books)

```
public class BookDto {
   private int id;
   private AuthorDTO author;
   private String title;
   private int year;

   // getter setter; 
}
```

Accordingly I need next DTO

```
public class AuthorDTO {
   private int id;
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName; 

   // getter setter;
}
```

Where and how I can aggregate this two DTOs?
For gettind data from DB i use JdbcTemplate. And I have methods getAuthorById (return Author), getAuthorsByIds (return List), getBookById (return Book), getBooksByIds (return List).

Now I create intermediate class

```
public class BookWithAuthor {
   private int id;
   private Author author;
   private String title;
   private int year;

   // getter setter; 
}
```

and next logic in service

```
List<BookWithAuthor> getBooksWithAuthors(Set<Integer> ids) {
    List<Book> books = getBooksByIds(ids);

    List<Author> authors = getAuthors(books);

    return books.stream()
            .map(book -> getBooksWithAuthors(book, authors)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private List<Author> getAuthors(List<Books> books) {
    Set<Integer> getAuthorsIds = books.stream()
            .map(Books::getAuthorId)
            .collect(toSet());

    return authorService.getAuthorsByIds(getAuthorsIds );
}

private BookWithAuthor getBooksWithAuthors(Book book, List<Author> authors) {
    BookWithAuthor bookWithAuthor= new BookWithAuthor();

    bookWithAuthor.setId(book.getId());
    bookWithAuthor.setAuthor(getAuthor(authors, book.getAuthorId()));
    // and next setting

    return bookWithAuthor;
}
```

I'm not sure is it right way or, maybe here is simplier ways.

Comment: you can define one-to-many mapping between Book and Author ENtity and fetch it in a single query.

Comment: can you show what is expected response in json?

Comment: {
    "id": 1,
    "author": {
          "id": 1,
          "firstName": "Stephen",
          "lastName": "King",
      },
    "title": "Dark Tower",
    "year": 1986
  }

List of this object

Comment: Perhaps not relevant to the question but JPA has a neat way of doing this with `@Embedded` and `@Embeddable` annotations. [Here's an example](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-embedded-embeddable).

Comment: I have to use JdbcTemplate. Single qeury also is not good idea, because each of my repositories must work with its own entity